# Reusing Supplier, Function and Consumer objects

Tags: java, android, completable-future

Currently I am using the `CompletableFuture` port from the [streamsupport](https://sourceforge.net/projects/streamsupport/) library to implement a chain of asynchronous tasks to perform some IO operations.

As the Function and Supplier objects became a bit too large for my taste, I wanted to move them, resulting in code like

```
private Function<Boolean, Boolean> getEmptyBufferFunction() {
    return new Function<Boolean, Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean apply(Boolean didPrecedingSucceed) {
            /* body */
        }
    }
};
```

While this works, I was curious whether this is good practice as they are re-created each time the method is called, or if a better practice is to have the implementation as final objects and re-use them. I.e.

```
private final Function<Boolean, Boolean> emptyBufferFunction = new Function<Boolean, Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean apply(Boolean didPrecedingSucceed) {
            /* body */
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: I've used this pattern extensively and would even recommend using `static final`. Isn't this Java 8 though? Because then you can just declare a function and refer to it by `ClassName::functionname`.

Comment: I always opt for the `static final` approach in such cases